# Белые списки для VpnService с добавлением DNS

Tags: android, dns

Есть пример написания VpnService с добавлением DNS и фильтрации трафика.

- Есть ли у кого опыт добавлений туда белый списков сайтов, чтобы они открывались в обход DNS?
- Как это организовать правильно?